# Caling UnManaged Code from Powershell - Handling Enum Type

Tags: powershell, pinvoke

I am using Powershell to call the group policy update API from userenv.dll (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/userenv/nf-userenv-refreshpolicy) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/userenv/nf-userenv-refreshpolicyex)). This works fine:

```c#
$sig =@'
[DllImport("userenv.dll", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
public static extern bool RefreshPolicy([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)] bool bMachine);
'@
```

```c#
$mytype = add-type -memberdefinition $sig -Name "Win32RefreshGP" -Namespace Win32Functions -PassThru
$mytype::RefreshPolicy($false) # Refresh the user policy
```

When I import this type though as follows:

```c#
$sigEx =@'
public enum RefreshPolicyOption:uint
{ 
    RP_FORCE = 1,
    RP_SYNC = 2 
}

[DllImport("userenv.dll", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
public static extern bool RefreshPolicyEx([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)] bool bMachine, RefreshPolicyOption dwOptions = 0);
'@
```

```c#
$mytypeEx = add-type -memberdefinition $sigEx -Name "Win32RefreshGP" -Namespace Win32Functions -PassThru
$mytypeEx::RefreshPolicyEx($false) # Refresh the user policy
```

The following is raised calling `$mytypeEx::RefreshPolicyEx($false)`

```
Method invocation failed because [System.Object[]] does not contain a method named 'RefreshPolicyEx'.
At line:1 char:1
+ $mytypeEx::RefreshPolicyEx($false) # Refresh the user policy
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound
```

This seems to be because of the attempt to use the enum in the type defintion. Any ideas?

I have tried using single/double quotes. I'd epxect the type definition to work as it works in C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is fairly simple, when you use `-PassThru`, `Add-Type` will output a type instance for every type defined in your C# inline code, in this case `$mytypeEx` will have 2 types, thus the error you're getting:

```bash
PS /> $mytypeEx

   Namespace: Win32Functions

Access        Modifiers           Name
------        ---------           ----
public        class               Win32RefreshGP : object
public        enum                Win32RefreshGP.RefreshPolicyOption : uint

PS /> $mytypeEx.Count
2
```

Solution is as simple as indexing the `Win32RefreshGP` type and then call its static member:

```bash
PS /> $mytypeEx[0]::RefreshPolicyEx($false)
```

Or you can remove `-PassThru` and then call the static member from the type itself:

```bash
PS /> [Win32Functions.Win32RefreshGP]::RefreshPolicyEx($false)
```

Comment: Thanks you so much Santiago. That makes sense now and it's working. The only differentce to your output I see though is my enum still shows as False for IsPublic. I'm using Powershell 5.1 on Windows 10 Enterprise 22 H2.

Comment: @shocko right but `.IsNestedPublic` will be `true` ;) no need to worry about that